# Using bccsp instance from chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

It is my understanding that in Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 we could use the BCCSP capabilities within the chaincode to help applications handle their own encryption.     My questions are,  is this assumption correct? If so, how can I get a handle of the BCCSP instance from the chaincode?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/bccsp/factory/swfactory.go#L62) code snippet.
However - note that keeping state in the chaincode is generally not a good idea and it is advised not to store state that is reused across chaincode invocations.

In the future there might be a built-in crypto library to be used by the chaincode developers.

Comment: I'll add to Yacov's answer and say that it's also possible to just use the encryption in Go's crypto libraries as well